# Auth0 error after failed login attempt

Tags: facebook, auth0

I am using Auth0 to authenticate users by redirecting them to facebook.
But the problem I am facing is that if a user types in incorrect account credentials the first time and succeeds on the second attempt the redirect does not happen, instead it takes me to "Oops!, something went wrong" page with the following message:
"invalid_request: You probably pressed the back button or there is some issue with cookies, since we couldn't find your session. Try logging in again from the application and if the problem persist contact the administrator."

EDIT: I am using the below Auth0Lock code on the client side.

```
 var lock = new Auth0Lock('<%= auth0.clientId %>', '<%= auth0.domain %>', {
 //redirect mode
     auth: {
       redirectUrl: '<%= auth0.callback %>',
       responseType: 'code',
       params: {
         scope: 'openid' // Learn about scopes: https://auth0.com/docs/scopes
       }
     },
     autoclose: true,
     theme: {
       logo: 'https://xxxxxx/logo_orange.jpg'
     },
     languageDictionary: {
       title: "test"
     }
 });
 lock.on("unrecoverable_error",function(err) {
       console.log(err);
 });
 lock.on("authorization_error",function(err) {
       console.log(err);
 });
```

Once I select Login with facebook I am redirected to facebook url that looks something like [link](https://www.facebook.com/login.php?skip_api_login=1&api_key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&signed_next=1&next=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fv2.8%2Fdialog%2Foauth%3Fredirect_uri%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Ftest.auth0.com%252Flogin%252Fcallback%26state%xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx%26scope%3Demail%252Cpublish_actions%26response_type%3Dcode%26client_id%xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx%26ret%3Dlogin%26logger_id%xxxxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx&cancel_url=https%3A%2F%2Ftest.auth0.com%2Flogin%2Fcallback%3Ferror%3Daccess_denied%26error_code%3D200%26error_description%3DPermissions%2Berror%26error_reason%3Duser_denied%26state%xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx%23_%3D_&display=page&locale=en_GB&logger_id=xxxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx)

There if I enter the email/password incorrectly the first time the page refreshes and on the second try if I succeed,instead of taking me back to my app the auth0 generic error page => [doc](https://auth0.com/docs/error-pages/generic) shows up with the error I mentioned at the top.On the server side passport seems to correctly authenticate the user.

PS: Chrome is taking me to a login page which has a login form on top and center but firefox just has login at the center of the page.For chrome if I use the top login form and has a failed login attempt on second successful attempt I am taken to my facebook page i.e no redirect happens.

Comment: Could not reproduce it in a quick test, I would suggest that you update your question with the exact steps you use to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @JoãoAngelo Have updated the description.Thanks for the help.

Comment: You can always reproduce it and across more than one browser? Also try it in a new Chrome incognito window. I used similar code and still not able to repro it, first attempt I'm providing wrong password then the correct one and I do get redirected to my application.

Comment: @JoãoAngelo What I can tell you is that its happening in chrome(As of now).Strangely in firefox the redirect flow is working smoothly.Managed to get the same error in chrome incognito mode.

Comment: @JoãoAngelo Managed to reproduce the error in firefox incognito mode.:)

Comment: You can try to capture an HAR (see [HAR files](https://auth0.com/docs/tutorials/troubleshootings-with-har-files)) and update the question with a link to it. **Be sure to obfuscate any sensitive information (paswords and such) before uploading it anywhere.**

Comment: @JoãoAngelo I have the HAR file but couldn't raise a support ticket due to some permission issue.:(

Comment: If you cleaned it up to ensure no sensitive info is included I would just uploaded it no any cloud storage provider you have access to and link to it in the question.

Comment: There is a lot of cookies in there,should they be obscured?

Comment: I only saw your last update now, I was always using the login form at the center of the page... if I use Chrome with the top form I get the problem. This seems to be a Facebook issue, give me a few minutes to dig a little deeper, but for now no need for the HAR (sorry for asking for that initially, but completely missed the other form).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's at least one issue and that one is a Facebook problem. Their login page is showing two login forms:

[image]

The `TOP` form has an `action` equal to:

> `https://www.facebook.com/login.php?login_attempt=1&lwv=100`

while the `CENTER` one has:

> `/login.php?login_attempt=1&next=https://www.facebook.com/v2.4/dialog/oauth?redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flogin.eu.auth0.com%2Flogin%2Fcallback&state=[state]&response_type=code&client_id=[client_id]&ret=login&logger_id=1bf0be0d-4b64-43a6-b112-79a30100fa5b&lwv=100`

This means that submitting the top form does not maintain enough information to be able to return back to your application. Now, there's still the issue of the Auth0 generic page being shown, but that one I'm unable to reproduce. If you think it's worthwhile, then do upload an HAR for review, even one where you strip all cookies might help.

---

**Update:**

Looked at the HAR, the second issue seems to be caused by an authentication request to Facebook that does not pass through Auth0. There's a request to your application, but that one does not complete an then there's this second request that will trigger the Auth0 error page.

Expected flow:

1. `https://test.auth0.com/authorize`
2. `https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth`
3. `https://www.facebook.com/login.php` (**user authenticates here**)
4. `https://www.facebook.com/v2.8/dialog/oauth`
5. `https://test.auth0.com/login/callback`
6. `https://localhost:8080/callback`

What's causing the error generic page, before your `localhost` request completes another request is issued:

1. `https://www.facebook.com/v2.8/dialog/oauth`
2. `https://test.auth0.com/login/callback` (**generic error page shown here**)

The error is caused because `https://test.auth0.com/login/callback` is called without first going through `https://test.auth0.com/authorize` to setup the authentication transaction state.

Given the request to your application `localhost` is marked as incomplete I would start looking in your code to see if there's any reason for that request to not complete.

Comment: Angelo Here is the [gist](https://gist.github.com/niwsa/c94093ed97ccf9a40c2062d0666e2537)

Comment: Just looked at it, it's a client-side issue, there's additional request being made after the login that are causing the error page, but the issue is that those request should not be made.

Comment: Looks like for chrome they have fixed the top login bar,now I am not seeing it.:)

Comment: Angelo does that mean there is something I am doing wrong(or missing) on my  server side /callback code?

Comment: It does seem to point to that, considering the call to your application did not finish correctly according to the trace. Although it's strange if this only happens when failing credentials once... I would suggest for you to create a [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and then post a new question with that full sample code.

Comment: Another strange thing is now I can't reproduce the problem.Tried both chrome and firefox its  working as expected.If you want me to file a MVCE I can do it but what info should I give there?

Comment: If you can no longer repro it, there's always the chance that this might've been a FB issue, you mentioned that the top form no longer appears, so they might have introduced changes that no longer causes this to happen. From my side, if your problem is solved, I'm good. :)

Comment: `    app.get('/callback',passport.authenticate('auth0',{ failureRedirect: '/login' }),function(req,res) {
            if(!req.user) {
                    throw new Error('user null');
                    res.redirect('/500');
            }
            // console.log(JSON.stringify(req.session));
             console.log(req.user.id);
             res.redirect(req.session.path || req.session.returnTo || '/') ;

    });
`

Comment: Earlier I used to wrap the remaining code in my callback under the else,I guess thats where the request were not completing,I have taken the last two lines where I am printing the user id and doing redirect out of else,So that it does something on every request.

Comment: Yes, that's correct, you should always respond with something to an HTTP request.